# Example of operator with spectrum equal to $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

In my Functional Analysis course, we proved that for a (possibly unbounded) operator $T$ that is densely defined, closed, and symmetric, exactly one of the following four occurs:

1. $\sigma(T) = \mathbb C$;
2. $\sigma(T) = \{\lambda \in \mathbb C \mid \Im \lambda \geq 0\}$;
3. $\sigma(T) = \{\lambda \in \mathbb C \mid \Im \lambda \leq 0\}$;
4. $\sigma(T) \subset \mathbb R$.

Now, 4 is easy; this is true for selfadjoint operators. I'm having a hard time coming up with an example for option 1; can you guys help me?

Comment: You have examples for 2 & 3?  If so, could you take a direct sum of those?

Comment: I actually dont -- if you come across one, let me know. :)

Comment: Pardon me for slight thread resurrection, but where might one find a proof of this result?

Comment: @Stromael see the second part of theorem X.1 in Reed/Simon “Methods of Modern Mathematicsl Physics”, Vol. 2, Section X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $T=\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dt}$ be defined on the domain $\mathcal{D}(T)$ consisting of all absolutely continuous functions $f \in L^2[0,1]$ for which $f(0)=0=f(1)$. More precisely, $f \in \mathcal{D}(T)\subset L^2[0,1]$ is an equivalence class of functions equal a.e. with one element $\tilde{f}$ of the equivalence class that is absolutely continuous on $[0,1]$ with $\tilde{f}'\in L^2[0,1]$. Then $T$ is closed and densely-defined. It's not hard to check that $T$ is symmetric:
$$
       (Tf,g)-(f,Tg) = \frac{1}{i}\int_{0}^{1}f'\overline{g}+f\overline{g}'dt=\left.\frac{1}{i}f\overline{g}\right|_{0}^{1} = 0.
$$
The resolvent equation is $(T-\lambda I)f=g$, which means
$$
                          f'-i\lambda f=ig,\;\;\; f(0)=0=f(1).
$$
Using an integrating factor $e^{-i\lambda t}$ and the fact that $f(0)=0$ must hold, you can see that the following is necessary:
$$
                    \frac{d}{dt}(fe^{-i\lambda t})=e^{-i\lambda t}ig \\
                   f(x)e^{-i\lambda x} = \int_{0}^{x}e^{-i\lambda t}ig(t)dt
$$
However, this is an actual solution iff
$$
                        \int_{0}^{1}e^{-i\lambda t}g(t)dt = 0.
$$
So there is no $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ for which a solution of the resolvent equations can be found for all $g$. Therefore $\sigma(T)=\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: what does mean densely-defined in simple words ?

Comment: @user1952009 : The domain $\mathcal{D}(T)$ is dense in the underlying space $L^2[0,1]$. That is, $\mathcal{D}(T)^c=L^2[0,1]$, where $\mathcal{D}(T)^c$ is the topological closure of $\mathcal{D}(T)$ in $L^2[0,1]$.

Comment: Agh, sure. Really easy and nice example; in fact, we've looked at this operator in some detail. Never did I think to compute its spectrum. Thank you.

Comment: @JanWesterdiep : You're welcome. Differentiation is a strange example of several things. If you compute the resolvent of $\frac{1}{i}\frac{d}{dt}$ on the domain with periodic conditions $f(0)=f(2\pi)$, you get first order poles at the integers, and the sum of the residues of $-(T-\lambda I)^{-1}f$ is the Fourier series for $f$.